# evaluating xpath 1.0 expressions with Saxon-HE 9.6.0-6

Tags: xpath, saxon

My project was using Saxon 9.0.0.2. I am trying to upgrade to Saxon-HE 9.6.0-6.

```
XPathEvaluator#setBackwardsCompatible(boolean)
```

this method no longer exists in 9.6.0-6.
I commented that line in my code, but when running i am getting following error:

```
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of name() (<xs:element/>, <xs:element/>, ...)
at net.sf.saxon.expr.Expression.typeError(Expression.java:1123)
at net.sf.saxon.expr.CardinalityChecker.evaluateItem(CardinalityChecker.java:295)
at net.sf.saxon.functions.NameFn.evaluateItem(NameFn.java:52)
at net.sf.saxon.functions.NameFn.evaluateItem(NameFn.java:23)
at net.sf.saxon.expr.Expression.iterate(Expression.java:448)
at net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:192)
at net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathEvaluator.evaluate(XPathEvaluator.java:239)
at jlibs.examples.xml.sax.dog.engines.SaxonEngine.evaluate(SaxonEngine.java:72)
at jlibs.examples.xml.sax.dog.TestCase.usingDOM(TestCase.java:71)
at jlibs.examples.xml.sax.dog.tests.XPathConformanceTest.run(XPathConformanceTest.java:44)
at jlibs.examples.xml.sax.dog.tests.XPathConformanceTest.main(XPathConformanceTest.java:73)
```

looks like, if `name` function throws this when the argument contains sequence of more than one element.

it used to work perfectly fine.
How to make it work without changing my xpaths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saxon now offers two APIs for XPath evaluation: the JAXP API and the s9api API. Saxon's implementation of the JAXP API has moved towards conforming as closely as possible with the JAXP specification, including dropping of extensions like the setBackwardsCompatible() method. However, XPathEvaluator allows you to access the StaticContext using getStaticContext(), and this has an option setBackwardsCompatibilityMode() which should restore the old behaviour.

Alternatively, there is also a method setBackwardsCompatible() on the s9api XPathCompiler class.

If you want to take advantage of XPath 2.0, you will probably want to move to the s9api interface, as JAXP has no support for the richer type system of XPath 2.0.